# per build configuration files on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm looking for the best way to store per-Build configuration information for an iPhone app. In my iPhone app there are several url's and storage location settings that are specific to a particular build (DEBUG RELEASE etc)

Currently i have three recipients for my app, QA/Test, myself and the customer, each has specific settings for the url's and storage locations mentioned above.

whats the best way to do this?

NOTE: they don't necessarily have to be defined in the build but what im looking for is advice on the best way to store alternate configuration settings.

ALSO NOTE: i do not want these settings to be editable through the settings app

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Xcode Build System Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/200-Build_Phases/bs_build_phases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002690-CJABHEIB).

One way to do it is to run a build script at the beginning of the build to copy a configuration file into the resources directory. Derive the location of the source file using the $CONFIGURATION variable. See [Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html) for a description of all of the variables.